# Makefile variable assignment based on an existence of a directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Looking for ways to assign a variable in a Makefile based on the existence of a directory.

Eg: (pseudo code)

```
if dir "src/$(project)" exists
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(project)
else
SOURCE_DIR := src/default

test.o: $SOURCE_DIR/test.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

What's the best way to achieve the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(shell test -d src/"$(project)" && echo "$(project)" || echo default)
```

Comment: Above works. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to test whether ${project} is NOT NULL, even before testing the existing of the directory using 'test'. That will make it more robust

Comment: This definitely works, but running the shell comes with issues such as performance (probably not a concern here) and portability: you can get the same result using built-in make functions to avoid them.

Answer (score 4):

As your source directory will contain files and a non-existing directory will not, you can utilize the GNU make internal function [`$(wildcard)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function):

```
project := test

# returns all entries under src/$(project) directory or empty string
ifneq ($(wildcard src/$(project)/*),)
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(project)
else
SOURCE_DIR := src/default
endif

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $(SOURCE_DIR)
```

Test run

```
$ ls src/test/
a.c
$ make
src/test

$ rm -rf src/test
$ make
src/default
```

---

**BONUS:** it might be more readable to rewrite the conditional like this:

```
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(project)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*),)
  # fall back to default directory
  SOURCE_DIR := src/default
endif
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** if you don't want to rely on the existence of any files in the directory, you can also test the directory name directly. A directory always has an entry `.`, because it points to itself:

```
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(project)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/.),)
  # fall back to default directory
  SOURCE_DIR := src/default
endif
```

---

**UPDATE 3:** adding a check that `$(project)` is set:

```
SOURCE_DIR := src/$(project)
ifeq ($(strip $(project)),)
  # fall back to default directory
  SOURCE_DIR := src/default
else ifeq ($(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/.),)
  # fall back to default directory
  SOURCE_DIR := src/default
endif
```

or if you prefer makefile Golfing (thanks @MadScientist for the suggestion)

```makefile
SOURCE_DIR := $(or $(and $(project),$(wildcard src/$(project)/.)),src/default)
```

- `$(and)` result

  - if `$(project)` is an empty string: empty string
  - if `src/$(project)` is not a directory: empty string
  - otherwise: `src/$(project)/.`, which is equivalent to `src/$(project)`
- `$(or)` result

  - if `$(and)` returns empty string: `src/default`
  - otherwise: the string returned by `$(and)`

---

**CAVEAT:** the above listed tests will fail if `$(project)` contains white space.

Comment: The best way to check for the existence of a directory is `$(wildcard $(DIR)/.)`.  The `.` will always exist in any directory and it will never accidentally match if `$(DIR)` is a file instead (as would `$(wildcard $(DIR))`).

Comment: An even simpler construct that avoids `ifeq` is `SOURCE_DIR := $(or $(wildcard src/$(project)/.),src/default)`

Comment: ahh yes, I should have remembered the `/.` from an answer that I gave a few weeks back :-)

Comment: If you want to test `project` for emptiness, you can use `$(or $(and $(project),$(wildcard src/$(project)/.)),src/default)`

Comment: @MadScientist can you provide an explanation as to how your suggestion works

Comment: @Mike please see [Functions for Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions)

Comment: Well, it's all about learning so still worth it even if not accepted :)